# which method is called when selecting a cell in the NSTableView in Cocoa OS X?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nstableview

I have a NSTableView , i want to get the value present in the cell. I am having only one column so , i just need the row number

i can use this [tableView selectedRow]- but where do i put this i want to put this in a method that gets called on selection of any of the rows.

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{

NSLog(@"%d",[tableViewController selectedRow]);

}
```

The above method also does not work i am getting the error 
-[NSScrollView selectedRow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100438ef0]

i want something like the method available in the iPhone tableview-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What is `tableViewController` object? Only `NSTableView` instances respond to `selectedRow`. You can get current table view (the one that sent the notification) from `notification`'s object property:

Objective-C:

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"%d",[[notification object] selectedRow]);
}
```

Swift:

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let table = notification.object as! NSTableView
    print(table.selectedRow);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the selected cell?

Comment: yes, tableView.selectedRow ...have a look here https://www.raywenderlich.com/118835/os-x-nstableview-tutorial it'll either return -1 if nothing is selected or 0,1,2,3,4 or whichever row is selected.

Answer (score 3):

my 2 cents for Xcode 10/swift 4.2

```
  func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let table = notification.object as? NSTableView else {
            return
        }
        let row = table.selectedRow
        print(row)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 5.4**:

Just use `tableView.action = #selector(YOUR_METHOD)`, then in your method, try to do something with `tableView.selectedRow`.

This would simply do the trick. Take a look at the demo below:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.

    tableView.action = #selector(didSelectRow)
}

@objc private func didSelectRow() {
    print("Selected row at \(tableView.selectedRow)")
}
```

But please be aware that if nothing is selected, or you clicked outside of a cell, then you'll get a `tableView.selectedRow` of **-1**. So you might wanna check if the index is out of range before you use it. :)

Comment: Works great, a lot easier than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 (from Eimantas' answer):

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let table = notification.object as! NSTableView
    print(table.selectedRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should addObserver Notification like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(tableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification)
                                             name:NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

It will action when tableView selected row

good luck

Comment: a bit overwhelming.. add and remove observers. we do have a delegate method, yet.

Answer (score 0):

full guide In **Swift 5**:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.didSelectRow(_:)), name: NSTableView.selectionDidChangeNotification, object: tableView)
    }



    @objc
    func didSelectRow(_ noti: Notification){
        guard let table = noti.object as? NSTableView else {
            return
        }
        let row = table.selectedRow
        print(row)
    }


    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```