# How to get index of currently selected row and column in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm working on a small MacOS app with a super simple NSTableView.
When the user select a cell I need to know the column and the row index of this cell.
I've implemented the method

`- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification`

and ask to the NSTableView for `selectedColumn` and `selectedRow`, but when I click on the table the result is always the selection of an entire Row. 
(in fact `selectedRow` return the right index number and `selectedColumn` return -1 = no selection)

**How can I select a single Cell and how can I know his coordinates?**

Thanks for any help!

[The selected row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syrb7.png)

Comment: `NSTableView` can select rows and columns but the user can't select a single cell. Do you want to get the column of the focused text field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which method is called when selecting a cell in the NSTableView in Cocoa OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796724/which-method-is-called-when-selecting-a-cell-in-the-nstableview-in-cocoa-os-x)

Comment: @Koen unfortunately in that question the programmer only ask for row number, but thanks for your comment

Comment: @Willeke oh, unexpected! My intent was to crate a small and simple “ExcelStyle” table, where user can select a specific cell. I don’t even need to edit the cell content directly, I just need to know where the user want the program to place new data. Maybe NSTableView is not the right way? Do you have any suggestion? P.S. when program start I don’t know how many column and row the user needs so I add them programmatically at run time. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Maybe `NSCollectionView` is what you are looking for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview?language=objc

Comment: @Koen thanks! A customizable layout is perfect for my app! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow. For completeness, I wrote my comment in answer - if it solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a grid or spreadsheet type layout it is better to use an `NSCollectionView`.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview?language=objc) for more info.