# NSTableView get selected row

Tags: objective-c, macos, uitableview, nsarraycontroller

I have a table view connected to an array controller and am able to populate the table with data. I want to be able to select a row and a handler be called. I've tried

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

but am unable to call the handler.

Working on a Mac app in Objective-C. How do I hook up this handler correctly or should I be using something different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which method is called when selecting a cell in the NSTableView in Cocoa OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796724/which-method-is-called-when-selecting-a-cell-in-the-nstableview-in-cocoa-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be using `UIKit` in a Mac application, instead you will use `AppKit`'s **`NSTableView`**.

### Create a column:

```
NSTableColumn * column = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"SomeColumnId"];
column.headerCell.stringValue = NSLocalizedString(@"Column Name", nil);
[_table addTableColumn:column];
```

### Set up the table:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return _someArray.count;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    if ( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"SomeColumnId"] )
    {
        return @"Some cell string"; // or _someArray[row][@"some_string_key"]
    }

    return nil;
}

-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ( [[notification object] selectedRow] == 0 )
    {
        /// first row was selected. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood...I'm still missing how to connect my table or array controller to this delegate. How do I do that?